# May all that is beautiful, meaningful, and brings you joy be yours this Holiday Season. --- parallelism?

Tags: parallelism

I found on a Christmas card sold in the U.S., and I know it's natural:

> May all that ***is beautiful, meaningful, and brings you joy*** be yours this Holiday Season.

But this re-configured version may be more appropriate in terms of parallelism:

> May all that ***is beautiful and meaningful, and brings you joy*** be yours this Holiday Season.

What do you think? I see the sentence parsed like this:

> May all that ***[is [beautiful and meaningful], and brings you joy]*** be yours this Holiday Season.

Answer (score 1):

Parallelism is about good English *style*, and not grammar.  Both of your examples exhibit good grammar.

When considering good style there are various considerations.  For example, the *rhythm* of the sentence -- does it flow with a natural cadence, ["trippingly on the tongue"](https://www.enotes.com/shakespeare-quotes/trippingly-tongue)?  Imagine you are saying this in a speech before a group.  Does it sound like something you would want to hear?  Does it sound like something someone else would want to repeat to others?

Forcing a more *parallel* construction can be like [pounding a square peg into a round hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_peg_in_a_round_hole), where you make the sentence worse simply to make it fit  Often the parallel construction is also the most pleasant-sounding, but sometimes you want to introduce a contrasting note to *emphasize* the odd element.

Those are questions for the writer and each reader to decide, individually.  But if you're going for maximum parallelism, as well as a pleasant rhythm, I would write:

> May all that is beautiful, and meaningful, and joyful, be yours this Holiday Season.

"Joyful" doesn't mean quite the same thing as "brings you joy", but I think it's close enough to convey the intention.

Comment: I like your advice, but I think your revised version has too many _ands_ and commas. I'd prefer: _May all that is beautiful, meaningful, and joyful be yours this holiday season._ (I'd also keep "holiday season" in all lower-case, but what do I know? I was never hired to write greeting cards!)

Comment: @J.R. I just imagine my father-in-law, whose oratory is the epitome of *gravitas*, saying this with the appropriate pregnant pause at each comma.  Then it sounds pretty good.

Comment: I'd still strike that comma after _joyful_. It seems [ungrammatical](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/commas/) to me.